# AlertDialog.Builder with custom layout and EditText; cannot access view

Tags: android

I am trying to create an alert dialog with an `EditText` object. I need to set the initial text of the `EditText` programmatically. Here's what I have.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
alertDialog.setContentView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null));
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label_field);
editText.setText("test label");
alertDialog.show();
```

What do I need to change so that I can have a valid `EditText` object?

[edit]

So, it was pointed out by user370305 and others that I should be using `alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.label_field);`

Unfortunately there is another issue here. Apparently, setting the content view on the `AlertDialog` causes the program to crash at runtime. You have to set it on the builder.

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null));
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
EditText editText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
editText.setText("test label");
alertDialog.show();
```

Unfortunately, when you do this, `alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.label_field);` now returns `null`.

[/edit]

Answer (score 282, accepted):

`editText` is a part of `alertDialog` layout so Just access `editText` with reference of `alertDialog`

```
EditText editText = (EditText) alertDialog.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
```

**Update:**

Because in code line `dialogBuilder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null));`

`inflater` is **Null**.

update your code like below, and try to understand the each code line

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
editText.setText("test label");
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
alertDialog.show();
```

**Update 2:**

As you are using View object created by Inflater to update UI components else you can directly use `setView(int layourResId)` method of `AlertDialog.Builder` class, which is available from API 21 and onwards.

Comment: U also can do it as:
`dialogBuilder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);`

Comment: @SiavA this method is available only form API 21.

Comment: I have been trying to display Dialog and it wasn't working in RecyclerView but this one did.

Comment: You can use `getLayoutInflater()` when the `inflater` is not defined.

Comment: how to close dialog?

Comment: @saigopi when you override onClick, there will be arguments (DialogInterface dialog, int id). In this onClick method, just pass dialog.cancel();

Comment: @Scaraux import the `android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog.Builder`

Answer (score 31):

Use this one

```
   AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    // Get the layout inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (activity).getLayoutInflater();
    // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
    // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the
    // dialog layout
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.setIcon(R.drawable.galleryalart);
    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialogue, null))
    // Add action buttons
            .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                    }
                }
            });
    builder.create();
    builder.show();
```

Comment: should be `builder.create().show();` , you can check the `builder.show();` code for more detail

Answer (score 12):

You can write:

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

 // ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater(); 

View dialogView= inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);                    
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

Button button = (Button)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.btnName);

   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View view) {

         //Commond here......

       }
   });

EditText editText = (EditText)
dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field); 

editText.setText("test label"); 

dialogBuilder.create().show();
```

Answer (score 6):

In case any one wants it in Kotlin :

```
val dialogBuilder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
// ...Irrelevant code for customizing the buttons and title
val dialogView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null)
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView)

val editText =  dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field)
editText.setText("test label")
val alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create()
alertDialog.show()
```

Reposted [@user370305's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/370305/user370305) answer.

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.label_field);
```

to this:

```
EditText editText = (EditText)  v.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_label_editor, null);
alertDialog.setContentView(v);
EditText editText = (EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
editText.setText("test label");
alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/**
 * Shows  confirmation dialog about signing in.
 */
private void startAuthDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

    alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(800, 1400);
    LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.auth_dialog, null);
    alertDialog.getWindow().setContentView(dialogView);
    EditText editText = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.label_field);
    editText.setText("test label");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making View `final`

eg:(with custom layout)

```
final View layout=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.create_class,null);
builder.setView(layout);
```

Comment: This question was from 2014. I'm not testing alternative solutions anymore.