# AlertDialog not Presenting correctly the dialog i wanted

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

i am trying to present an alertdialog in my actvitiy which describe if the user doesnot have some information stored in my database then a alertdialog will popup in front of the user with button.
here is my code for the dialog in activity

```
AlertDialog.Builder myAlert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
myAlert.setMessage("You are winner!").setPositiveButton("Continue...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    }
})
.setTitle("Welcome")
.create();
myAlert.show();
```

so basicly i am not getting the desired alertdialog i wanted,i am getting something like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwTyK.png).

i have no borders between title and message and button, my button not placed at center as default ,what should i do to fix these i have tried many videos and posts.

Comment: this is default material design `alert dialog`, you will need to create `custom layout` for `alert dialog`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2795300/how-to-implement-a-custom-alertdialog-view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have no borders between title and message and button, my button not
>   placed at center as default ,what should i do to fix these i have
>   tried many videos and posts.

In case, if you don't like the material dialog and you want to platform's specific dialog then you should use **android.app.AlertDialog** in place of **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog**.

Change the import statement from **android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog** to **android.app.AlertDialog**

But I recommend you go with material dialog box.

Comment: i changed the import setence it still give me the same dialog.

Comment: Then I guess, you are running your app on a lollipop device or emulator.

Comment: I have changed the min sdk and i guess i used other theme and it worked perfectly thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should use custom dialog for this purpose. Create a custom layout. And setlayoutview to the dialog.

sample code

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonShowCustomDialog);

    // add button listener
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {

        // custom dialog
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom);
        dialog.setTitle("Title...");

        // set the custom dialog components - text, image and button
        TextView text = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.text);
        text.setText("Android custom dialog example!");
        ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
        image.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Button dialogButton = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.dialogButtonOK);
        // if button is clicked, close the custom dialog
        dialogButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });

        dialog.show();
      }
    });
```

See details at below link

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder myAlert= new AlertDialog.Builder(this, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog);

    myAlert.setTitle("Welcome")
.setMessage("You are winner!")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Continue...", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    //do things
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = myAlert.create();
    alert.show();
```

Comment: i tried to use your line of code instead it just present the same dialog in full screen.

Comment: it opened the dialog in full screen and not like pop up in the picture i uploaded.

Comment: Then you have to check the sdk version you are using and the adt version

Comment: android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.barhom.waves"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    } been stuck in this problem for 1 day i canot solve it ...

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/swz9so6botv6toc/Screenshot_2015-10-13-15-57-26.png?dl=0 i am trying different themes but not getting the right results , i am still seeing the dialogbox with no borders between title and message and button.