# Implementing actions (add/edit/delete) on ListView items

Tags: java, android, listview, menu, menuitem

I am sort of new to Android since I've done only some basic applications, but I'm more familiar with Java. I've been working on an application which should provide **LoginActivity** with two attributes that generate one *Pair* connection (**IP address** and **port**) at the top of the screen and a **ListView** of all already known connections (which were occasionally used before) right under the button "Connect".

[Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQ0Bd.png)

My question is, how to implement some actions like **add/edit/delete etc.** when holding on a finger little longer on certain item in the ListView? How to make some menu for **modification/deletion** of already known connections?

Here's the code that I already got for the ListView:

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    if (v.getId()==R.id.list_view) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_list, menu);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.edit:
            //implement here
            return true;
        case R.id.delete:
            //implement here
        default:
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: As using ContextMenu is certainly a valid option, it is a bit outdated in my opinion. I would recomend to make a layout with three buttons and either overlay it on the item selected with longclick, or use something like [this library](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout) to expand this layout below. That's just a suggestion, ContextMenu still is an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have forgotten register your context menu to listview?

```
registerForContextMenu(lv);
```

EDIT

ok, now I understand. Maybe this will help:

```
 case R.id.delete:

     int index = info.position;
     listView.remove(index);
     listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I think you didn't understand, I've done that already but the points of interest are the "//implement here" lines

Comment: Thanks for your time, but I've already known the procedure for delete, I'm asking how to make window with EDIT action

Comment: In R.id.edit just create AlertDialog with custom layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view

Comment: and in positive button callback just change right item in your listViewAdapter list, then call listViewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();