# AlertDialog White Part At The Bottom

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog, android-dialog

I am using AlertDialog but android adds white space at the bottom of AlertDialog.

I found that the problem is happening when i use the

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);
```

The creation of AlertDialog is done like :

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
builder.setView(layout);
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); //Controlling width and height.
```

I show the AlertDialog in a Fragment class and Fragment class belongs to AppCompatActivity.

How to remove this white space ?

[image]

Comment: can you share screenshot

Comment: I added my tablet screen shot.Below of the bottoms there is a white space.

Comment: it is because of alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);

Comment: Make your Parent layout height to match_parent

Comment: use https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view

Comment: Can you post your xml?

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
`alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);`

to wrapping things use `wrap_content` in your xml file.

Check one more thing, have you used any layout element with static height or not. Should use `wrap_content` in all parent xml elements.

You can also use `android:background="#80000000"` // transparent code in parent most layout element.