# Is it possible to replace AlertDialog layout?

Tags: android, layout, dialog

I've been trying to create a customized AlertDialog and I know that I can use [`AlertDialog.Builder.setView()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setView(int)) to put a custom view inside the dialog, but is it possible to completely replace the default layout?

EDIT:
I want to do this because it would allow me to use the builder's `setMessage()`, `setTitle()` etc. with a custom layout

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AlertDialog.Builder with custom layout and EditText; cannot access view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view)

Comment: You can always fall back to Dialog, and then you can control everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is possible to Customize or completely change `Dialog` or `AlertDialog` ,You can Customize `Dialog` as like this

```
private void customDialog() {
        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActivityUserVideoPlay.this, R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.your_layout_foor_dialog); // your custom view.
        dialog.setCancelable(false);
        dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        dialog.show();
    }
```

And this is styles for dialog

```
 <style name="MaterialDialogSheet" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>
    </style>
```

Use animation to open or close your dialog as you want otherwise you can remove it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: this does not answer the question directly, but creating a custom Dialog instead of hacking the AlertDialog makes sense

Comment: it's not any Alert Dialog Hack it also works as AlertDialog you can use any of dialog with same properties

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can, you just have to create the `.xml` and inflate it. Just like that:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
        View alertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.newsletter_dialog, null);

        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        builder.setView(alertView);
        final AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
```

Comment: this is exacly what I described I didn't want to do - this places the view inside the AlertDialog's layout