# Alert dialog info button

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am a beginner in android programming and I have noticed, that my tablet Sony Xperia Z4 (Android 6.0) got an alert dialog with 3 buttons: **positive**, **negative** and **the other one**, see in the picture below. This is main menu, not my application.

[Alert Dialog info button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9uHF.jpg)

My question: is this a custom dialog? I have never met with this type of button in alert dialog.

Thank you.

EDIT:

Duplicate? I don't think so... 
[AlertDialog.Builder with custom layout and EditText; cannot access view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view)

Why?

- User got a problem with accessing an edit text in his dialog.
- *My question is*, if dialog in my tablet is CUSTOM. Nothing else :)

Comment: I don't think so... My question and your link -> two different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an AlertDialog, instead is just a Dialog with a custom layout, you can do it, you can bind buttons and views to a Dialog and make a custom one like the image you posted. Here is a post that might help you out

[How to create a Custom Dialog box in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android)