# Default Alert dialog with different style

Tags: android

I want to use the default Alert dialog with a message an 2 buttons.
However, I want to style it differently. So the buttons text color and size, the title text color, size and background.
Do I need to create a custom dialog or is there a way I can change the default one without having to create a custom dialog?
Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change theme for AlertDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422562/how-to-change-theme-for-alertdialog)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to create a new layout xml file, for example `dialog_layout.xml`. Design your dialog just like you design any activity. Then, before you create the dialog with the builder, and after `builder.create(getActivity())`, call`builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout)` and it should look exactly the way you want it.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view) is a similar question that you can read through

EDIT: small correction

Comment: I was asking if there is a way to do it "Without" it being custom dialog, ie my own layout