# Set message text to fit width of AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm applying a hard-coded value `----` into the message body of a custom AlertDialog. In my device, it fits well since I used its dimesions, like below:

[image: Normal device]

However on a large screen device, it will definitely appear different like this:

[image]

and the code to produce the dialog:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
    .setTitle("Title goes here...")
    .setMessage("-------------------------------")
    (…)
```

I can use `DisplayMetrics` to get the width of the dialog, but how do I now apply the width caught to the actual message?

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
final int DisplayWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder gives you a AlertDialog. You can call `findViewById` on it and get any view on the AlertDialog. Then you can get width of the message textview.
Also, you can use a custom layout for your alert dialog using `setLayout` in the builder.

Answer (score 0):

you can create xml for custom AlertDialog and in xml file set title and below line(View Tag with `layout_heigh = "1dp" layout_width = "match_parent"`).

Answer (score 0):

I think, you want to show the layout.xml in alertDialog. And apply as in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22655641/5451586). You can put an ImageView instead of the line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just 1 line in the message of the dialog, then set the message

```
"-------------------------......"
```

to be more than long enough for any device's line.
The message of the `AlertDialog` is a `TextView` that can be found by `findViewById()` and invoke its method `setSingleLine(true)` or `setlines(1)`.

```
    AlertDialog ad = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    TextView message = ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    message.setSingleLine(true);
    ad.setTitle("Title goes here...");
    ad.setMessage("----------------------.....");
    ad.show();
```

Comment: `TextView message = ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
    message.setSingleLine(true);` is returning a NullPointerException

Comment: Which line of the 2 returns NPE?

Comment: `message.setSingleLine(true);` this, even after initializing it

Comment: I really can't see why `ad.findViewById(android.R.id.message)` cannot find the message `TextView` inside the `AlertDialog`. Do you have this exact line in the imports of your class: `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog`?