# why Android dialog title not showing on android versions marshmallow?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dialog, customdialog

I was trying to create a custom dialog here is my code :

```
        val myDialog = Dialog(this)
        myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.my_dialog)
        myDialog.setTitle("My Dialog!")
        myDialog.setCancelable(true)
        myDialog.show()
```

Here is my_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:text="Hello world!"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

I have run this on android version lollipop It works fine here is screenshot on lollipop :

[image: Dialog on Android version Lollipop]

as you can see dialog title is showing but when I try to run this on Android version marshmallow title stop showing here is screenshot on marshmallow :

[image: Dialog on android version marshmallow]

as you can see dialog title not showing on android version marshmallow. I have try adding this line for showing title :

```
myDialog.create()
```

but title still not showing. what should I do?

Comment: Use Linear/Relative layout for this

Comment: @AbhinavGupta I have already tried but title still not showing on marshmallow.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried applying custom style... The dialog adopts the Style of the parent Activity which might have been set to NoTitle.

```
<style name="CustomDialog" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
</style>
```

On the java code

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(Context, R.style.Dialog))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am using dialog I cannot use alert dialog in my case.

Answer (score 1):

Use AlertDialog instead of Dialog.

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(getString(R.string.disclaimer))
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot use alert dialog because setView requires api level 21 and I cannot use dialog and alertDialog together in  my case.

Comment: @AndroidExpert refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view you can also set custom layout with alert dialog.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already tried alertDialog but if i use alert dialog I can't cancel or dismiss it.

Comment: @AndroidExpert you can dismiss it. Use setCancelable(true) && just look at my code & look Ok click button, by using dialog.dismiss() you are able to dismiss it. :)

Comment: Thanks, but in my case I need to close alert dialog out side of button how can I call dialog.dismiss() or dialog.cancel()  out side of button?

Comment: set alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true)