How to handle dismiss requests from Dialog launched from a Composable passed as a variable
I want to create a composable to handle generic settings which display a Dialog (e.g. to replace the EditTextPreference and ListPreference of Androidx Preference API).
The idea is that this GenericSettingWithDialog accepts in input the Composable handling the Dialog content:
@Composable
fun GenericSettingWithDialog (
    name: String,
    state: State<String>,
    dialogContent: @Composable ()-> Unit
) {
    var isDialogShown by remember {
        mutableStateOf(false)
    }
    if (isDialogShown) {
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = {
            isDialogShown = false
        }) {
            dialogContent()
        }
    }
    // setting row launching the dialog, with title and graphics
}

Unfortunately, this implementation is not able to handle dialog dismiss requests coming from the dialog itself, like when clicking the Confirm button.
I am working on the possibility of using Kotlin's Function literals with receiver as shown in this answer:
Jetpack Compose function with lambda () -> Unit, but still unclear how.

I use AlertDialog instead, that one has a dismissButton and confirmButton handler build in

@user3791775 unfortunately not, I need Dialog because I need to customize its aspect and behavior

@perissf use AlertDialog  and customise it using https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22655599/alertdialog-builder-with-custom-layout-and-edittext-cannot-access-view

@BobSmith unfortunately not, the question is related to Android Compose not VIews

If you want to dismiss dialog on the a event of dialogContent then we can pass a lamda function in the dialogContent: @Composable ()-> Unit like below.

Updated GenericSettingWithDialog code

@Composable
fun GenericSettingWithDialog (
    name: String,
    state: State<String>,
    dialogContent: @Composable ( onDismiss: (() -> Unit)? )-> Unit
) {
    var isDialogShown by remember {
        mutableStateOf(true)
    }
    if (isDialogShown) {
        Dialog(onDismissRequest = {
            isDialogShown = false
        }) {
            dialogContent(){
                isDialogShown = false
            }
        }
    }
    // setting row launching the dialog, with title and graphics
}


While using above function follow as below

GenericSettingWithDialog("abc",str){onDismiss->
        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .size(250.dp)
            .background(Grey1)){
            Box (modifier = Modifier
                .size(50.dp)
                .background(Color.Red)
                .clickable {
                    onDismiss?.invoke()
                }){

            }
        }
    }

Here onDismiss is called when you want to dismiss dialog from dialogContent
Cheers!!
